# In regard to the list of suggestions

Tags: word-choice

Is it right to say `In regard to the list of suggestions...`?

I've used Grammarly and the Algorithm suggested to chance to `Regarding to the list`.

Is it different? How?

Comment: “Regarding to the list” is never correct. “Regarding the list” could work. Could you provide more context?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***In regard(s)*** to/of something is effectively the same as ***regarding*** that same thing, but *regarding* is more natural in most dialects I've come across.

***Regarding to/of*** is just not right.

Comment: can both be used at the beginning of a sentence?

Comment: @AndrewTobilko: yes.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing wrong with the phrase "in regard to".  You can also use the phrases "with regard to", "in connection with", "in respect to", "with respect to", or as regards instead, without any difference in meaning.  However, the use of regarding/concerning as follows is more idiomatic and common:

Regarding/concerning the list of suggestions....